# In this code, are we inserting a linked list at the beginning, at a specific position or at the end?

Tags: c

```c
void sll_insert()
{
    int i;
    nn = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    
    if(nn == NULL) {
        printf("\n memory allocation failed...");
        return;
    }
    
    printf("\n enter the item:");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    
    nn->info = i;
    nn->link = NULL;
    
    if(start == NULL)
        start = curr = nn;
    else
    {
        curr->link = nn;
        curr = nn;
    }
}
```

Sorry, I'm just a beginner and my college provided me this code and I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: This awful code inserts a new node in the end of the list.

Comment: Tell your colleague to apply proper formatting to any code. That is a mess. Indentation is important. Especially for beginners.

Comment: Using as few globals as possible is important too. Use arguments instead.

Answer (score 2):

If `start` is a pointer to the begin of the list and `curr` a pointer to the last element of the list, then it is inserting the element at the end of the list.
It sets the new node `nn` to be the one after `curr` and `curr` is set to point to `nn`.

This code is very confusing though. Variable `nn` is not declared in the scope of the function and `start` and `curr` seem to be globals.

Here are a few hints to improve this function:

- Variable `nn` should be declared in the scope of the function.
- A pointer to `start` (yes, a pointer to a pointer) should be passed to the function.
- You can compute `curr` by iterating over the list so no need to store it outside the function, unless you're interested in doing things efficiently.
- It would be better if your function returns an error code (for example -1) in case of malloc failure.

Comment: +1. Some more additions could be: 1) Do not cast the result of `malloc()`. 2) print error messages to `stderr` instead of `stdout`. 3) Run the code under an automatic code formatter, such as GNU indent.